# Publish CMS (by Sundell) compiling for wrong platform version

Tags: swift, content-management-system, swift-package-manager

I created a new [Publish: A static site generator for Swift developers](https://github.com/JohnSundell/Publish) project with `publish new` in the terminal.
When building the project in Xcode I get this error:

"The package product 'Publish' requires minimum platform version 12.0 for the macOs
platform, but this target supports 10.10"

I'm on macOS 12.4, Xcode 13.4.1, Swift 5.6.1 and Publish 0.9.0.
I've only got one installation of Xcode installed, and xcode-select points to this installation.

I've tried to set the platform version in the Package.swift file:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "MySite",
    platforms: [
        .macOS(.v12_4)
    ],
    products: [
        .executable(
            name: "MySite",
            targets: ["MySite"]
        )
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(name: "Publish", url: "https://github.com/johnsundell/publish.git", from: "0.7.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MySite",
            dependencies: ["Publish"]
        )
    ]
)
```

But this gives me another error instead:

"Reference to member 'v12_4' cannot be resolved without a contextual type" and "Cannot build "MySite" without a run destination. Select a run destination to perform this action."

I can not choose a destination because as it says: "No devices because active scheme has no targets".
And sure enough if I look at my scheme it says my target it missing, which isn't a surprise since it hasn't been build yet.

I've tried to open older projects (both my own and others) and there is no errors with them. And it's possible to choose a destination (My Mac).

I've tried to compare a new project with one of the older projects, but I can't for the better of me see where the difference in behaviour comes from.

So the question is, where to set the right platform version for compiling?
If this wasn't a Swift Package I could have set this in the Project Editor, but this option is not there for packages.

Comment: The syntax for platforms is `.macOS(.v12)` in Package.swift so you can't select a specific 12.x version

Comment: Thank you Joakim!
Setting platforms to .macOS(.v12) and swift-tools-version to 5.5 or above (at the top of the Package.swift file) solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.macOS(.v12) was introduced in Package Description 5.5.

Setting it to .v12 and setting the swift-tools-version to 5.5 or above (at the top of the Package.swift file) fixes this issue.

Thanks to [Joakim Danielson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9223839/joakim-danielson) for solving it.